Caplet volatility formula
Consider an ATM caplet with maturity $T$ and delivery $T+\tau$.
In the book Interest Rate Models (Brigo and Mercurio), page 81, the authors define the model caplet volatility
as the unique value of $\sigma$ such that the formula
$$P(0,T+\tau)\cdot \tau f_\tau(T;0)\left(2\Phi \left( \frac{\sqrt{T}\sigma}2\right)-1\right) = (P(0,T) - P(0,T+\tau))\left(2\Phi \left( \frac{\sqrt{T}\sigma}2\right)-1\right) $$
is equal to the caplet price produced by the model in question.
Here $f_\tau(T;t)$ is defined (page 12, (1.20)) by
$$ f_\tau(T;t) = \frac{1}{\tau} \left( \frac{P(t,T)}{P(t,T+\tau)} -1 \right).$$
Then, they say

The left-hand side is the market Black's formula for a $T$-expiry $(T+\tau)$-maturity at-the-money caplet.

So my question is, where is this expression coming from in the author's book? Why is the forward rate $f_\tau(T;0)$ showing up?

Note: the error was using the incorrect model, but I leave the computation here (for log-normal bond prices, not forward rates).
If we consider the martingale $F_t = \frac{P(t,T+\tau)}{P(t,T)}$ in the $T$-forward measure, and notice that $1+\tau f_\tau(T;t) =  F_t^{-1}$ then it is clear that an ATM caplet gives an ATM bond put, and the formula for the bond put is
$$ P(t) = P(t,T) (K \Phi(-z_-) - F_t \Phi(-z_+)) $$
where $z_{\pm} = \dfrac z \sigma - \dfrac \sigma 2$ and $z = \log \frac{F_t}K$ is the log-moneyness. When the option is at the money, $z=0$, $K = F_t$ and $F_t P(t,T) = P(t, T+\tau)$, so
$$ P_{\mathsf{ATM}}(0) = P(0,T+\tau) \left(2\Phi \left(\frac\sigma 2\right) - 1\right) $$
and multiplying by $F_0^{-1}$ gives the pre-factor $P(0,T)$ instead for the caplet.

There are many typos in your derivation in 1. The volatility term cannot be bare of $\sqrt{T},.$ Most importantly I think your error is in thinking that the forward of our underlying is that of a zero bond. It is not. We are looking at a forward rate. The author's (of whom you did not tell us the  names) formulas look totally right.

@KurtG. The abscence of $\sqrt{T}$ simply happens because $\sigma$ is calculated as a term volatility which will incorporate it directly. This I am sure is correct. For the forward: In the book, they use the notation $F(0;T,T+\tau)$ instead of $f_\tau(T;0)$ but they mean the same, and in page 12 (1.20) they write the formula for this number which is what I wrote. So, the authors are talking about forward rates for zero bonds.

(For example, see Equation 11 in https://people.kth.se/~aaurell/Teaching/SF2975_HT17/calibration-hull-white.pdf where there is also no explicit $\sqrt{T}$. It is there in the term variance)

Brigo and Mercurio's ATM caplet formula is undoubtedly correct. Your relationship between the interest rate $f_\tau(T;t)$ and the forward bond price $F_t=\frac{P(t,T+\tau)}{P(t,T)}$ is also correct. However, you wrote "then it is clear that an ATM caplet gives an ATM bond put". How? Please elaborate. :)

@KurtG. Perhaps that's where I'm off. The bond strike is $1/(1+\tau K)$. When $K$ is the forward rate, this is equal to the bond forward price, or not?

Even that is true :) But you should not jump forward so quickly. Compare the payoffs of caplet vs bond put. There is no linear relationship. Traders often say an interest rate call is a bond put but this is only a way of saying when things go ITM/OTM. The pricing formulas do not have to agree that simply.

@KurtG. Ok, my understanding is that $\mathsf{Caplet}\tau(T,K;t) = (1+\tau K) \mathsf{BondPut}\tau(T,X;t)$ where $X = (1+\tau K)^{-1}$, where the LHS is the price at time $t$ of a $T$ maturity $T+\tau$ delivery caplet with strike $K$, and where the RHS is the price at time $t$ of a put on a $T+\tau$ bond  with maturity $T$ and strike $X$. So I agree that the relation is not linear in $K$, but still when  $t=0$, $K=f_\tau(T;0)$ we have that $X = F_0$ the bond forward price and $\mathsf{CapletATM}\tau(T;0) = F_0^{-1} \mathsf{BondPutATM}\tau(T;0)$. So where I am mistaken?

This  notation shows again that you have not examined the first principles properly. We cannot challenge Brigo & Mercurio by messing around with function inputs like engineers. Perhaps the following is the final stab: in BM they assume that $f_\tau(T;t)$ is lognormal (Black 76 model). Your bond is $\frac 1{1+\tau f_\tau(T;t)}$ and on that you want to price a put with the caplet volatility. Question: can this bond be possibly lognormal? Then and only then you will get that Black & Scholes formula.

@KurtG. Ah, I see. That clears things up.

@KurtG. Ok, I've added an answer. Thanks for the clarification!

To clear any doubt, I will write down the calculation here.
To be concrete, we let $f(t) = f_\tau(T;t)$ for some interval
$[T,T+\tau]$, we assume that under the $T+\tau$ forward
measure we have that $df(t) = \sigma(t) f(t) dW(t)$ where
$\sigma(t)$ is some deterministic function of $t$.
Thus, our numeraire is the process $P(t,T+\tau)$.

Under the Black model, the price of a $T$ maturity $T+\tau$
delivery caplet with strike $K$ is given by the Black formula
$$
\mathsf{BlackCaplet}_\tau(T,K;t) = 
P(t,T+\tau) \tau \left( f(t) \Phi\left( z_+ \right) 
    - K \Phi\left( z_{-}\right) \right).
$$
where $z_\pm = \frac{z}{\sigma} \pm \frac{\sigma}{2}$,
$z = \log \frac{f(t)}K$ is the log-moneyness and
$\sigma^2 = \int_t^T \sigma(s)^2 ds$ is the
term volatility.

Proof.
Using Ito's formula we see that
$$d \log f(t) = \sigma dW(t) - \frac 12 \sigma^2 dt$$
so that
$$ \log f(T) = \log f(t) + \int_t^T \sigma(s)dW(s) 
    - \frac 12 \int_t^T \sigma(s)^2 ds.$$
The payoff of a $T$-maturity caplet with strike $K$ at time $T$ is
$\tau (f(T) - K)^+$, so we know that the fair price of a
caplet at time $t$ is
$$ \mathsf{BlackCaplet}_\tau(T,K;t) = 
\tau P(t,T+\tau) \mathbb{E}((f(T)-K)^+ \mid \mathcal F_t) 
$$
where the expected value is taken under the $T+\tau$
forward measure. Since, conditional on $\mathcal F_t$,
$\log f(T)$ is normal, we see that we want to compute
$$
\mathbb{E}((X-K)^+) \text{ where }\log X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)
$$
where $\mu = \log f(t)  - \frac 12 \int_t^T \sigma(s)^2 ds$
and $\sigma^2 = \int_0^T \sigma(t)^2 dt$. A routine calculation
shows that in this case
$$
\mathbb E((X-K)^+) = 
    f(t) \Phi\left( z_+ \right) - K \Phi\left( z_{-}\right) .
$$
where $z_\pm = \frac{z}{\sigma} \pm \frac{\sigma}{2}$ and
$z = \log \frac{f(t)}K$ is the log-moneyness. This gives
the formula.
When the caplet is at the money, we get
$$ \mathsf{BlackCapletATM}_\tau(T;t) = 
P(t,T+\tau) f_\tau(T;t) \tau \left( 2\Phi\left(\frac\sigma 2\right)  -1 \right)
$$
which is the formula in the book.
